# uitableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath "selected row not loading the detail view"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have a table view with 7 rows, I want to click on my rows and load the detailView( uiViewController )

I can select the row and I can see the Log in console but it never loads the detail view

would you please give me some hits, what is the problem?

```
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
NSLog(@"selected rows");

MyBookDetailView *c = [[MyBookDetailView alloc] init];

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:c animated:YES];
}
```

I also try performSelectorOnMainThread but still it just clickable and I have problem to load my view controller, I also add delegate in - (void)viewDidLoad method,

Thanks in advance!

lates code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
MyBookDetailView *c = [[MyBookDetailView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyBookDetailView" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:c animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Can you check 2 things: 1. Is the viewDidLoad method on MyBookDetailView is called? 2. Can you try after removing this statement: [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

Comment: Pop and Push in together. If navigationController is not nil. I suggest to manipulate viewControllers stack of navigationController for process it in one time.

Comment: @AC1 I put NsLog on viewDidLoad MyBookDetailView but it never print it, I also remove this statement  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO]; but nothing happen

Comment: Its very likely that your self.navigationController is nil then. Can you verify that? Is your self embedded in a navigation controller?

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to pop up all controllers withing navigationcontroller stack to root controller and same time your want to push up new  MyBookDetailView (i hope its base class is UIViewController).

Anyways,  `MyBookDetailView *c = [[MyBookDetailView alloc] init];` also will not work for you. Because  **c** object of UIViewController (MyBookDetailView) view is nil. I recommend use break point trace execution stack and variable that you trying to remove and adding on run time you will better know what going on in your program.

I think following code may work for you,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    MyBookDetailView *c = [[MyBookDetailView alloc] initWithNibName:@"WriteYourNibNameIfYouCreate" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:c animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, MyBookTableView is UITableViewController and also MyBookDetailView is UIViewController your code didn't work

Comment: here is myBookTableView http://pastebin.com/6EcTcPBM and here is detailView http://pastebin.com/XjxJxQsV

Comment: @ElnazShahmehr i'm talking about/regarding MyBookDetailView class nib and its based class. If MyBookDetailView class has nib file then your must mention its name on allocation time.

Comment: Yes I did I will send you the latest one

Comment: i still found     MyBookDetailView *c = [[MyBookDetailView alloc] init]; ....where is initWithNibName:bundle method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38562/discussion-between-elnaz-shahmehr-and-iambitious)