# How can I Push a new Table View at didselectrowatindexpath?

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode7

```
I am new to iPhone Development. I am trying to push a new table view at didSelectRowAtIndexPath of previous table.
```

I don't understand what logic should work.

here is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

dentalDoc = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"one ",@"two",@"Three", nil];
dentalDocImage = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ProfilePicRound",@"MapiCon",@"ProfilePicRound",nil];

searchDocList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Mary D'souza",@"Eric Josephson",@"Robert Adler",@"Lee Gold",@"Kevin Hansen",@"Karen Ziselman",@"Brad Gosky",@"Mark kogan",@"John Kong",@"Justin kohen",@"Oren Rehmanan",@"Paul Baker",@"Devashish Agarwal",@"Allen Chamberlin",@"Todd Lasner",@"Ryan walsh",@"steven Loan",@"Shrikant Mehta",@"Alexander lobo",nil];

doctorProfileImageList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ProfilePicRound",@"MapiCon",@"ProfilePicRound",@"MapiCon",@"ProfilePicRound",@"MapiCon",@"ProfilePicRound",@"MapiCon",@"ProfilePicRound",@"MapiCon",@"ProfilePicRound",@"MapiCon",@"ProfilePicRound",@"MapiCon",@"ProfilePicRound",@"MapiCon",@"ProfilePicRound",@"MapiCon",@"ProfilePicRound",@"MapiCon",nil];}
```

and other table view methods.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

// Return the number of sections.
return 1;}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
if (docsInt==0)
{
    return [dentalDoc count];
}
else
{
return [searchDocList count];
}}
```

and also cellForRowAtIndexPath Method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *cellIdentifier  = @"cell";
SearchCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if(docsInt == 0)
{
    cell.lblDocName.text = [dentalDoc objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imgProfile.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[dentalDocImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

}
else
{
cell.lblDocName.text = [searchDocList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.imgProfile.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[doctorProfileImageList objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]];

}
return cell;}
```

I am trying to retrieve doctor list for example , Dentist, MBBS , BHMS.
After selecting Category I want to retrieve Doctors names List table selected by category.

Please reply as soon as possible.

Comment: do you use story board?

Comment: set tag for tableview , just change the tag on didselectRow and reload table simple

Comment: yes I am using storyboard.

Comment: I want to retrieve table view format in only one view controller.

Comment: for example if I select Dentist. 3 of dentist data in table view format show to searchListController. while i select MBBS. then List of Docter related to MBBS doctor will retrieve by searchListController.

Comment: if the number of row are limits you can just update the data source at did select with new data source but if you want to push to another table view at didselect use  [self.navigationController pushViewController:table 2 animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard then use below code

```
DetailViewController* detailViewController =
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewControllerID"];

if([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(showViewController:sender:)])
    [self.navigationController showViewController:detailViewController sender:self];
else
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:animated];
```

Also you can refer : [uitableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath "selected row not loading the detail view"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165530/uitableview-didselectrowatindexpath-selected-row-not-loading-the-detail-view)

Hope this is useful

Comment: pushViewController is succesfully run. searchListController also appear. but it displays only dentist related data. not other categories data.

Comment: Can you please share your project in ZIP and mail to me, I will check it

Comment: I have found solution please check below.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution for this.
here is my code.

I have collection view. which contains following Arrays in view did load method of menuViewController.

```
searchIcons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"empty-filter-xl",@"icon_place",@"ProfilePicRound",@"green_heart_rate",@"MYP",@"Maps-icon", nil];
searchNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Dentist",@"MBBS",@"Psychiatrist",@"Cardiologist",@"Nurologist",@"Orthopedic",nil];
```

And these are collection view methods.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return searchIcons.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
FilterCollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.imgFilterIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[searchIcons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.lblFilterCategory.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[searchNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

return cell;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

SearchList *svc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyBoardIdentifier"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];

if ([[searchNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:@"Dentist"])
{
    svc.docsInt = 0;

}
else if([[searchNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:@"MBBS"])
{
    svc.docsInt = 1;
}
else if([[searchNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:@"Psychiatrist"])
{
    svc.docsInt = 2;
}
else
{
    svc.docsInt = 3;
}
}
```

In didSelectItemAtIndexPath user will push to SearchList View Controller which display a table view acording user select doctor's category.

here is the code for searchList view controller.

List of arrays as per doctor's category.in view did load method.

```
 dentalDoc = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"one ",@"two",@"Three", nil];
dentalDocImage = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ProfilePicRound",@"MapiCon",@"ProfilePicRound",nil];

mbbsDoc = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"MBBS 1",@"MBBS 2",@"MBBS 3",@"MBBS 4",@"MBBS 5",@"MBBS 6",@"MBBS 7", nil];
mbbsDocImage = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"MapiCon",@"ProfilePicRound",@"MapiCon",@"ProfilePicRound",@"MapiCon",@"ProfilePicRound",@"MapiCon", nil];

PsychiatristDoc = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Doctor 1",@"Doctroe 2",@"Doctor 3",@"Doctor 4",@"Doctor 5", nil];
PsychiatristDocImage = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"empty-filter-xl",@"icon_place",@"ProfilePicRound",@"green_heart_rate",@"MYP",nil];

searchDocList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Mary D'souza",@"Eric Josephson",@"Robert Adler",@"Lee Gold",@"Kevin Hansen",@"Karen Ziselman",@"Brad Gosky",@"Mark kogan",@"John Kong",@"Justin kohen",@"Oren Rehmanan",@"Paul Baker",@"Devashish Agarwal",@"Allen Chamberlin",@"Todd Lasner",@"Ryan walsh",@"steven Loan",@"Shrikant Mehta",@"Alexander lobo",nil];
doctorProfileImageList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ProfilePicRound",@"MapiCon",@"ProfilePicRound",@"MapiCon",@"ProfilePicRound",@"MapiCon",@"ProfilePicRound",@"MapiCon",@"ProfilePicRound",@"MapiCon",@"ProfilePicRound",@"MapiCon",@"ProfilePicRound",@"MapiCon",@"ProfilePicRound",@"MapiCon",@"ProfilePicRound",@"MapiCon",@"ProfilePicRound",@"MapiCon",nil];
```

And this is table view methods.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
if (docsInt==0)
{
    return [dentalDoc count];
}
if (docsInt==1)
{
    return [mbbsDoc count];
}


 if (docsInt == 2){
   return [PsychiatristDoc count];}
else
{
    (docsInt == 3);
    return [searchDocList count];
}}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *cellIdentifier  = @"cell";
SearchCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if(docsInt == 0)
{
    cell.lblDocName.text = [dentalDoc objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imgProfile.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[dentalDocImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
else if (docsInt == 1)
{
    cell.lblDocName.text = [mbbsDoc objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imgProfile.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[mbbsDocImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
else if(docsInt == 2)
{
    cell.lblDocName.text = [PsychiatristDoc objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imgProfile.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[PsychiatristDocImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
else
{

    cell.lblDocName.text = [searchDocList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imgProfile.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[doctorProfileImageList objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]];
}
    return cell;}
```

And last but not the least a navigation method.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
// Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Detail"])
{
    NSIndexPath *indexpath = [tblList indexPathForSelectedRow];
    DoctorProfile *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    //destViewController.doctorName = [

    if (docsInt == 0)
    {
        destViewController.doctorName = [dentalDoc objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
    }
    if (docsInt == 1)
    {
        destViewController.doctorName = [mbbsDoc objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
    }
    if (docsInt == 2)
    {
        destViewController.doctorName = [PsychiatristDoc objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        destViewController.doctorName = [searchDocList objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
    }


}}
```

Thank You.